# NameServer is not working . Bind server have errors

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, domain-name-system, centos

I am new to webmin. I have followed 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rV9x6DVKxHg video tutorial for the setting up name servers.

But my Bind is not working now :( I am getting the following errors . 
I am using CENT OS .

```
[root@f9pix ~]#  /etc/init.d/named start
Starting named:
Error in named configuration:
zone localhost.localdomain/IN: loaded serial 0
zone localhost/IN: loaded serial 0
zone 1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.ip6.arpa/IN: loaded serial 0
zone 1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 0
zone 0.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 0
zone f9pix.com/IN: NS 'ns1.f9pix.com' has no address records (A or AAAA)
zone f9pix.com/IN: not loaded due to errors.
_default/f9pix.com/IN: bad zone
                                                           [FAILED]
```

Comment: Learning DNS and system administration from a *video*... OMG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not add the `A` or `AAAA` record for your `ns1.f9pix.com` host that maps the name to the `ipv4` or `ipv6` addresses correspondingly. So, the `bind` complains. So, if this is the same `f9pix` host then add one more record for its IP address with name `ns1` or fix `SOA` and  `NS` records to point to `f9pix.com` host

Comment: Please can explain me in details, i am using webmin ! I need Instruction to complete it !

Comment: sorry, I am not familiar with webmin.

Comment: @SandeepKamble try to follow http://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin/BINDDNSServer#Adding_and_editing_records to add `A` record for name `ns1.f9pix.com` that points to its IP address in the zone `f9pix.com`

Comment: okay i am reading it ! lets see